# How to add HEADER in apache_request_headers in PHP

Tags: php, apache, http-headers, slim, request-headers

I want to add a header, to request headers, dynamically on the server side.

I am using **slim 2** framework which supports middleware.

**Here is my usecase:**

- Client initiates request to url "https://somedomain.com/login" with some Request Headers.
- I have middleware say authenticate. Which should add say "UserAddress" to Request Header.
- My callback function login() is called. And I need to access "UserAddress" from header.

So following is the code for this route:

```
function login() {
    //Login related stuff
    $allHeaders = apache_request_headers();
    //Perform some operation on UserAdress from $allHeaders
}

function authenticate(\Slim\Route $route) {
    //Perform authentication here
    //I am using SUPERFICIAL method `set_apache_request_headers` as reference.
    //Here I need to know how I can add new header to REQUEST HEADER
    set_apache_request_headers('UserAdress', 'New York');
    //Here is what I tried, which did not work when I called apache_request_headers()
    //$_SERVER["UserAdress"] = "New York";
}

$app = getSlimInstance();
$app->post('/login', 'authenticate', login);
```

I tried using **$_SERVER**, but when I call **apache_request_headers()**, my header does not show up.

**Side Note:**
I am using "UserAddress" as my header for reference purpose. Actually I am using different name.
Also I know you guys will say pass that via request body. But due to legacy code I need this in request header.

***I just need to know how can I modify the Request Header***

Comment: is it an authorization header ? Because if it is, then there is specific format you have to set it in

Comment: PHP evaluates the request headers once before your script is started, and that is what apache_request_headers will then return. Trying to add additional (fake) request headers from within your already running script, is not going to impress PHP in any way.

Comment: @KaustubhKadam Does No it is not an authorization header

Comment: @misorude I Guess I am screwed then.